# Set settings without quotes

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to update Sublime settings using it's API. Here is the code for this task:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class FileNameOnStatusBar(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_activated(self, view):

        sublime.load_settings("Preferences.sublime-settings").set("wrap_width", "80")
        sublime.load_settings("Preferences.sublime-settings").set("word_wrap", "true")
        sublime.save_settings("Preferences.sublime-settings")
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
{
    wrap_width: 80,
    word_wrap: true
}
```

And this is what I currently get:

```
{
    wrap_width: "80",
    word_wrap: "true"
}
```

As you can see, in the second example the values are placed inside quotes, and this is the reason why it doesn't work.

How it may be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the values are being quoted is because you are passing strings to the `set` method. Use the appropriate Python datatype instead.

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class FileNameOnStatusBar(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_activated(self, view):

        settings = sublime.load_settings("Preferences.sublime-settings")
        settings.set("wrap_width", 80)
        settings.set("word_wrap", True)
        sublime.save_settings("Preferences.sublime-settings")
```

Comment: Wow, yes, it works. I'm surprised, because I've already tried it many times before. But in my tests, I used lowercase `t` in word `True`. With uppercase, it is now fixed.